# I have this kind of Error in php

Tags: php, sql

I have this kind of error in file upload in php. It gives me headache to find the answer. when I retrieve the variable of a certain file upload, I cant retrieve it. heres my codes.

```
 //this is the php code for validating all post and pass it to db
<?php
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$pic = '';
$message = '';  

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    include_once('database.php');
    _addstocks($_POST);
    $message = 'New Stocks Record Added';
    echo $_POST['ipic'];

}
function post_value($key)
{
    if(isset($_POST[$key]))
        echo  htmlentities($_POST[$key]);
}

?>
```

//this is my form or the data to be pass to the db

```
<form class="modal-content container" style="width:445;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <br>
                <label>Item Code</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="icode" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Code" required autofocus><br>
                <label>Item Name</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="iname" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Name" required><br>
                <label>Item Description</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="idesc" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Description" required><br>

                <!--<label>Item Type</label><br>-->
                <input type="text" class="hidden" name="itype" value="perishable">
                <label>Item Price</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="iprice" placeholder="Item Price" class="form-control" required><br>
                <label>Item Quantity</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="iqty" placeholder="Item Quantity" class="form-control" required><br>
                <input type="text" class="hidden" name="estabno" value="<?php echo "01";?>">
                <div enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label>Upload Display Picture</label><br>
                    <label for="fileToUpload"><img src="photos/<?php echo $pic;?>" style="width:100px;height:100px"></label>
                    <input class=""type="file" name="ipic" id="fileToUpload"><br>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="hidden" name="istat" value="available">

        <?php echo htmlentities($message);?>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right;" >
        <br><br><br>
    </form>
```

and this the database for adding the stocks

```
function _addstocks($stocks)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO inventory
    (
        itemcode,
        itemname,
        itemdesc,
        itemcateg,
        itemprice,
        itempic,
        estabno,
        itemqty,
        status

    ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $db = database();
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute(array(
        $stocks['icode'],
        $stocks['iname'],
        $stocks['idesc'],
        $stocks['itype'],
        $stocks['iprice'],
        $stocks['ipic'],
        $stocks['estabno'],
        $stocks['iqty'],
        $stocks['istat'])

    );
    $db = null;
}
```

and this is the error i get.
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvd6U.png

Comment: What "kind" of error? Btw, `['ipic']` is a file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to access them via $_FILES["ipic"]["tmp_name"]
Refer to: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Basically, a file is not a $_POST/$_GET type of request. It is part of the $_FILES one. That page should show you some good usage on it.

Change:

```
echo $_POST['ipic'];
```

To:

```
echo $_FILES["ipic"]["tmp_name"]
```

To access the file, But this will only give you a path to the file which is a temp path.. You still need to move the file or deal with it. Noticed, in your database your trying to insert it directly..

You will want to move the file to a folder using "move_uploaded_file" in that link, and then store the name of the url/path to the file in the database so that way you can link to it.

It is also possible to store certain items say like a base64 version of a file, but depends on your overall design.

Comment: how come in my customer add is I can add the file in the database while in my add stocks I cant?

Comment: Well we can only answer what we see in the post, But if you go by what i've written above. This will resolve your issue.

Comment: now i added what u want to be added but another problem "ipic" is undefined how can  i solve it?